# Is it bad practice to nest an if statement inside a switch statement?

Tags: switch-statement, coding-style

Is the following code sample of bad practice using an if statement inside of a switch statement? Someone laughed at me when I told them this is how I was applying some logic in my switch statement and thought it was ridiculous to put an if statement inside a switch statement:

```
switch(x)
{

  case 1:
   if(y==1){
     return b;
   } else {
     return c;
   }
   break;

   case 2:
   .....

   break;
}
```

Comment: For me personally no, let's say you want to parse user input `x` with `switch` , execute some functions passing `x` as an argument inside the `switch` blocks and finally return a value that needs to be compared with something else. As long as your code is clean, structured and readable why would that be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is usually okay to do so, but a cleaner approach would be to move this block:

```
if (y==1)
{
    return b;
} 
else 
{
    return c;
}
```

Inside a function that takes `y` as a parameter, like so:

```
switch(x)
{

    case 1:
        return func(y);
        break;

    case 2:
        …
        break;
}

func(y) 
{
    if (y==1)
    {
        return b;
    }
    return c;
}
```

This makes the code a bit clearer and easier to maintain, but apart from that there's no other major problem in doing such a thing.